# How to show or display "OK" button on UI dialog after 3 seconds in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show or display the UI dialog "OK" button after 3 seconds, so that background process is complete and then user clicks "OK" button to reload the page to see the saved data.

```
   $("#submit").click(function(p){
        $(function(){
        $('#saveinfo').dialog({
           modal: true,
           height:100,
           dialogClass: 'no-close',
           autoOpen: false, 
           position: ['middle',300],
           buttons:{
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        OK:function(evt) {
                            $('#saveinfo').dialog("close");
                            location.reload();
                          }
                    }, 3000);
                }
              
             }); 
        $('#saveinfo').dialog( "open" );    
      });
    
     });
```

Comment: You cannot use `setTimeout()` in that way. Your best option is to disable to button upion initialization and then use `setTimeout()` in the `open` callback to change it from Disabled to Enabled.

Comment: Could you please show me the example code?

Comment: I cannot without you providing a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var save = false;

  $('#saveInfo').dialog({
    modal: true,
    height: 140,
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog": "no-close",
      "ui-dialog-titlebar": "hide-btn",
      "ui-dialog-buttonpane": "compressed"
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    position: ['middle', 300],
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok",
      class: "disabled",
      disabled: true
    }],
    open: function(event, ui) {
      var $diag = $(this).dialog("widget");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("button.disabled", $diag).removeClass("disabled").button("enable");
      }, 3000);
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
      save = true;
    }
  });

  $("#submit").click(function(event) {
    if (!save) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#saveInfo').dialog("open");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-btn button {
  display: none;
}

.ui-dialog div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.compressed {
  padding: .25em;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.ui-dialog div.ui-dialog-buttonpane.compressed .ui-dialog-buttonset button {
  padding: .2em .4em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<div id="saveInfo">
  Some Content
</div>
```

> Each element of the array must be an object defining the attributes, properties, and event handlers to set on the button. In addition, a key of `icon` can be used to control button's icon option, and a key of `showText` can be used to control button's text option.

There are some undocumented indexes as well, such as Class and Disabled. The Dialog Widget makes use of the Button Widget when it builds the button. So you can make use of those Options when specifying the Buttons via Array.

Ref:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons
- https://api.jqueryui.com/button/